# XmlDocument.WriteContentTo(xmlwriter) not writing to my stream

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing, xmlwriter

I wrote a small function that formats an XmlDocument's indentation and preserves UTF-8 encoding. Problem is that I can't seem to WriteContentTo my XmlWriter instance. Is my implementation wrong on this?

```
function Format-XML ([xml]$xml, $indentChars = "  ")
{
        $xmlSettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
        $xmlSettings.Indent = $True
        $xmlSettings.IndentChars = $indentChars
        $xmlSettings.Encoding = $global:Utf8NoBomEncoding
        $xmlSettings.NewLineChars = "\r\n"
        $xmlSettings.NewLineHandling = [System.Xml.NewLineHandling]::Replace

        $xmlMemoryStream =  New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
        $xmlWriter = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($xmlMemoryStream, $xmlSettings)
        $xml.WriteContentTo($xmlWriter)
        $formatedAndEncodedXMLString = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($xmlMemoryStream.ToArray())
        $XmlWriter.Flush()
        Write-Output $formatedAndEncodedXMLString
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to flush before dumping the stream to the array?

Comment: It worked!! Not sure why though... still learning, will have to read more about streams. if you submit this as answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Data was sitting in internal buffers. This is to optimize when writing to files/sockets etc. It is more effective to write a bigger block of data then just on byte at a time. Flushing (as well as closing) makes sure that data from internal buffers are written to the actual target. (note that there is one more level here since you use XmlWriter and MemoryStream and flushing the writer flushes the stream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush the writer before dumping the stream to the array.

Data was sitting in internal buffers. This is to optimize when writing to files/sockets etc. It is more effective to write a bigger block of data then just on byte at a time. Flushing (as well as closing) makes sure that data from internal buffers are written to the actual target. (note that there is one more level here since you use XmlWriter and MemoryStream and flushing the writer flushes the stream)